# Sentinel 1 imagery in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-1

Do the Sentinel 1 Ground Range Detected imagery available in GEE as `ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S1_GRD")` require no correction at all and are ready to use? The 5 pre processing steps mentioned are already done? If not, does GEE purposes a way to perform these 5 corrections?

Answer (score 1):

It's a general question and it's depend on your goal and what you are looking for to do with the data. For most of cases you can start  your analysis with these preprocessing steps.
Also, there is no need for any atmospheric correction in radar data.

Comment: Thanks @Ofir for your response. I want to use it along with Sentinel 2 imagery for land cover classification. You are right about atmospheric correction. I deleted the tag. I just mean corrections